# How to install a powershell module within a docker container from an on-prem Azure Artifacts repository using PAT?

Tags: powershell, docker, tfs, azure-devops

I have the following situation:

1. On-prem Azure DevOps Server 2019.
2. Internal Powershell module published to the Azure Artifacts in (1).
3. A docker container needs to install the module from (2).

I can curl the Azure Artifacts NuGet repository from within the container:

```
PS C:\azp> $Uri
https://tfs.xyz.com/tfs/DefaultCollection/_packaging/xyz@Release/nuget/v2
PS C:\azp> $headers

Name                           Value
----                           -----
Authorization                  Basic ***


PS C:\azp> (curl $Uri -Headers $headers -UseBasicParsing).StatusCode
200
```

But I cannot install the module from it:

```
PS C:\azp> $Name
xyz
PS C:\azp> $credential

UserName                     Password
--------                     --------
a        System.Security.SecureString


PS C:\azp> Register-PSRepository -Name $Name -SourceLocation $Uri -PublishLocation $Uri -InstallationPolicy Trusted -Credential $credential
PS C:\azp> $Params

Name                           Value
----                           -----
Name                           xyz.PS.Core
Force                          True
ErrorAction                    Stop


PS C:\azp> $RepoParam

Name                           Value
----                           -----
Repository                     xyz


PS C:\azp> Install-Module @Params @RepoParam -Scope CurrentUser -Credential $credential
WARNING: Cannot access 'https://tfs.xyz.com/tfs/DefaultCollection/_packaging/xyz@Release/nuget/v2'. Are you missing 'Credential' parameter in the cmdlet?
WARNING: Unable to resolve package source 'https://tfs.xyz.com/tfs/DefaultCollection/_packaging/xyz@Release/nuget/v2'.
PackageManagement\Install-Package : No match was found for the specified search criteria and module name 'xyz.PS.Core'. Try Get-PSRepository to see all available registered
module repositories.
At C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\PowerShellGet\1.0.0.1\PSModule.psm1:1809 char:21
+ ...          $null = PackageManagement\Install-Package @PSBoundParameters
+                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Microsoft.Power....InstallPackage:InstallPackage) [Install-Package], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NoMatchFoundForCriteria,Microsoft.PowerShell.PackageManagement.Cmdlets.InstallPackage

PS C:\azp>
```

The `$credential` object contains the PAT as the password, but since I could not specify the empty user name, I give 'a' instead. But it does not seem to matter.

So, I do not understand how to install a Powershell module from the Azure Artifacts when running inside a container. Is it possible at all?

**P.S.**

I am using Windows 10. The base image for the interactive container is created from this docker file:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:ltsc2019
COPY certificates certificates
WORKDIR /azp
COPY test.ps1 .
COPY Token.txt .token
CMD powershell .\test.ps1
```

Where test.ps1 is:

```
Get-ChildItem /certificates | ForEach-Object {
    $null = Import-Certificate -FilePath $_.FullName -CertStoreLocation Cert:\LocalMachine\Root
}
```

**EDIT 1**

```
PS C:\azp> Get-PSRepository

Name                      InstallationPolicy   SourceLocation
----                      ------------------   --------------
xyz                       Trusted              http://tfs.xyz.com:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/_packaging/xyz@Release/nuget/v2
PSGallery                 Trusted              https://www.powershellgallery.com/api/v2


PS C:\azp> Get-PackageProvider

Name                     Version          DynamicOptions
----                     -------          --------------
msi                      3.0.0.0          AdditionalArguments
msu                      3.0.0.0
NuGet                    2.8.5.208        Destination, ExcludeVersion, Scope, SkipDependencies, Headers, FilterOnTag, Contains, AllowPrereleaseVersions, ConfigFile, SkipValidate
PowerShellGet            1.0.0.1          PackageManagementProvider, Type, Scope, AllowClobber, SkipPublisherCheck, InstallUpdate, NoPathUpdate, Filter, Tag, Includes, DscResou...
Programs                 3.0.0.0          IncludeWindowsInstaller, IncludeSystemComponent


PS C:\azp>
```

**EDIT 2**

There is an important detail I forgot to mention - I want to authenticate using PAT.

Comment: Forgive me for questioning the basics, but have you checked whether the container and the Azure DevOps Server can talk to each other? i.e. are they on the same network or publicly accessible via internet, are necessary ports (443?) are open/forwarded? Can you talk to the server via a simple ping / HTTP GET?

Comment: Yes, I did. Please notice in the beginning of the post I curl the url to show that container can successfully reach the nuget repo in Tfs. It is in the post.

Comment: What happens when you run Get-PSRepository is your repository showing up with a OneGetProvider of nuget? Also why are you use the v2 endpoint and the the v3?

Comment: v2 endpoint is what must be used when accessing the nuget repository to fetch powershell modules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Confirmed as a bug in Azure DevOps 2019 - https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/comments/885584/view.html

Comment: Thanks for sharing your feedback, mark. This issue has been reported to the product team, if there are any updates, the product team will share it in that developer community case. Appreciate your patience.

Answer (score 0):

There is a missing for 'Credential', this error indicates the $credential parameter you passed might be wrong.

The `-Credential` parameter requires a `PSCredential` as documented in [Install-Module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/powershellget/install-module?view=powershell-6).
But from the output of the $credential you posted, we know it is not a pscredential object.

Please try below script to [create a Pscredential](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/koteshb/powershell-how-to-create-a-pscredential-object).

```
$secpasswd = ConvertTo-SecureString "PAT" -AsPlainText -Force
$mycreds = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential("username", $secpasswd)
```

Then run `Install-Module` Command with the pscredential $mycreds

```
Install-Module @Params @RepoParam -Scope CurrentUser -Credential $mycreds
```

> Please make sure the PAT is valid and have Packaging: Read, write & manage permission. You can also check the detailed example [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/tutorials/private-powershell-library?view=azure-devops).

[image]

Comment: What is the user name? Is it my user name (because it is my PAT)? Is it domain name qualified?

Comment: I tried your suggestion and it does not work - the error message is exactly the same. Have you tried it yourself?

Comment: It works when using the user password, but I specifically want to use PAT. I have edited the question title and added **EDIT 2**

Comment: Hi @mark I have tested myself. It worked for me using PAT.  and the *username* can be any string. Please make sure your PAT is not expired and also have the `Packaging: Read, write & manage` permissions. I got the same credential missing error when I use a PAT without Package write&manage permission. I updated with my screenshot

Comment: The token is a Full Access token. Have you tested with a Full Access token?